# Python regex help for capturing groups of capital letters

Tags: python, regex, pypdf

I'm trying to capture ticker symbols from a handful of PDFs, specifically looking for groupings of 5 capital letters in a row (screenshot sample of PDF below). I have gotten my code to work for most PDFs but am running into trouble with one file in particular.

From the attached image, my goal would be to get a result of WFBFX, PRHIX, BBCPX, etc in a list. My code is below, I keep receiving a blank output. The idea for now is that the code scrapes the PDF, finds the groupings of capital letters in parentheses, creates a list, and spits that list out:

```
import pandas as pd
import PyPDF2
import re
import tqdm
import itertools

pdf_file = open(r'C:\Users\cummans\Jareds_code\Python\PDF Scrape\PDF Files\RJ Rec List.pdf', 'rb')
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
pdf_reader.numPages
ticker_ls = []

for i in range(pdf_reader.numPages):
    page_obj = pdf_reader.getPage(i)
    txt =page_obj.extractText()
    ls1 = re.findall("([A-Z]{5})", txt)
    ticker_ls.append(ls1)
    
check = list(itertools.chain(*ticker_ls))
clean_ticker_ls = list(dict.fromkeys(check))
clean_ticker_ls
```

For the regex I have also toyed around with the following line that has worked most places besides this one.

```py
ls1 = re.findall("\((.{5})\)", txt)
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are quite close

```py
import PyPDF2
import re

pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader('C:\Users\cummans\Jareds_code\Python\PDF Scrape\PDF Files\RJ Rec List.pdf')
ticker_ls = []

for page_obj in pdf_reader.pages:
    txt = page_obj.extractText()
    ls1 = re.findall("([A-Z]{5})", txt)
    ticker_ls.extend(ls1)
print(ticker_ls)
```